# How to enable more debugging info for DirectX variables in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, directx

I was able to enable debugging info for directX variables like LPD3DXMESH etc.

Normally it just shows IUnknown and a some pointer value, but if additional debugging is enabled its possible to see more detailed info about the structure.

Problem is that I lost the project and now I can't remember how to enable this type of debugging again.

Please help me find it again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you enabled DirectX debug mode? If not, go to the DirectX Control Panel under "Microsoft DirectX SDK/DirectX Utilities" in the Start menu and enable debug mode (Check the checkbox "Use Debug Version of Direct3D").

Next, make sure that your projects build configuration is set to Debug. In Visual Studio, choose Build > Configuration Manager and change the configuration of your project to Debug.

Finally, make sure to define D3D_DEBUG_INFO as described in [Enabling Direct3D Debug Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173355(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Yes, have put it in debug mode and ticked all the other debugging options there. 

Have the project in debug and using the d ending dependencies.

I can work without it but it helped a lot having access to all mesh internal variables etc. so you could see what's wrong value or corrupted.