# How do I draw to the deskop using directX?

Tags: c++, windows, directx

After figuring out how to draw a sprite and examining the possible parameters for each function and some extensive googling I can't find out how to draw to the desktop, can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Here is what I have tried already and what happened, I am using the following code as a learning point for my program:

```
// main.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//
#include "C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2008)\Include\D3dx9core.h"
#include "C:\Documents and Settings\Death\My Documents\Downloads\DXSprite\DXSprite\resource.h"
#include <windows.h>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GLOBALS
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HWND                              g_hWnd                    = NULL;
LPDIRECT3D9                 g_pD3D                  = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9           g_pD3DDevice            = NULL;
ID3DXSprite *               g_pD3DXSprite           = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9          g_pTexture              = NULL;
const int                   SCREEN_WIDTH            = 800;
const int                   SCREEN_HEIGHT           = 600;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// PROTOTYPES
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
HRESULT InitializeD3D       ( );
void RenderFrame            ( );

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: WinMain()
// Desc: The application's entry point
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                int       nCmdShow )
{
WNDCLASSEX  winClass;
MSG         uMsg;
HRESULT     hr;

memset(&uMsg,0,sizeof(uMsg));

winClass.lpszClassName = "MY_WINDOWS_CLASS";
winClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
winClass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
winClass.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
winClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
winClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDC_DXSPRITE);
winClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDC_DXSPRITE);
winClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
winClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
winClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
winClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
winClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;

if( !RegisterClassEx(&winClass) )
    return E_FAIL;

g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx( NULL, "MY_WINDOWS_CLASS",
                         "Direct3D 9 - ID3DXSprite Example",
                         WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                         0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

if( g_hWnd == NULL )
    return E_FAIL;

ShowWindow( g_hWnd, nCmdShow );
UpdateWindow( g_hWnd );

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Create the DirectX device
//----------------------------------------------------------------
if (FAILED( InitializeD3D()))
    return 0;


//----------------------------------------------------------------
// CREATE THE ID3DXSprite
//----------------------------------------------------------------

// Create the ID3DXSprite interface object
hr = D3DXCreateSprite(g_pD3DDevice, &g_pD3DXSprite );
if( FAILED(hr) )
    return hr;


//----------------------------------------------------------------
// LOAD THE TEXTURE FOR THE SPRITE
//----------------------------------------------------------------

// --------------------------------------------------------
// Load the texture.  I decided to use the extended
// version of the texture loading function just to show what
// it would look like.
// The texture was created with Photoshop with a transparent
// background to start with.  Then line cross hairs were added.
//
// Note - If you don't use a texture image that has a power of
// 2 size for the width or height then the image may not load
// properly.  This image is 256x256.
//
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(
    g_pD3DDevice,
    "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Death\\My Documents\\45handold2.tga",              // Our texture image!
    D3DX_DEFAULT,               // width
    D3DX_DEFAULT,               // height
    D3DX_DEFAULT,               // MIP levels
    0,                          // usage
    D3DFMT_DXT1,                // texture format
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED,            // mem pool
    D3DX_DEFAULT,               // filter
    D3DX_DEFAULT,               // MIP filter
    0,                          // transparent color key
    NULL,                       // image info struct
    NULL,                       // palette
    &g_pTexture);               // the returned texture, if success

if ( FAILED(hr) )
    return hr;





// ---------
// Main Loop
// ---------
while( uMsg.message != WM_QUIT )
{
    if( PeekMessage( &uMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &uMsg );
        DispatchMessage( &uMsg );
    }
}

// -------------------------
// Release directx resources
// -------------------------
if (g_pD3DXSprite)
{
    g_pD3DXSprite->Release();
    g_pD3DXSprite = NULL;
}

if (g_pTexture)
{
    g_pTexture->Release();
    g_pTexture = NULL;
}

if (g_pD3DDevice)
{
    g_pD3DDevice->Release();
    g_pD3DDevice = NULL;
}




UnregisterClass( "MY_WINDOWS_CLASS", winClass.hInstance );
return (int)uMsg.wParam;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: WindowProc()
// Desc: The window's message handler
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND   hWnd,
                         UINT   msg,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam )
{

switch( msg )
{
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        switch( wParam )
        {
            case VK_ESCAPE:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;

        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    break;

    default:
    {
        RenderFrame();
        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
    }
    break;
}

return 0;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: InitializeD3D()
// Desc: Create DirectX interface objects
//       Initialize the view matrix.
//       Setup render states that will not need changing throughout
//       the life of the application.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitializeD3D( )
{
HRESULT hr;

// Create a direct 3D interface object
g_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

if( g_pD3D == NULL )
{
    // TO DO: Respond to failure of Direct3DCreate9
    return E_FAIL;
}

D3DDISPLAYMODE d3ddm;

if( FAILED( hr = g_pD3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &d3ddm ) ) )
{
    // TO DO: Respond to failure of GetAdapterDisplayMode
    return hr;
}


//
if( FAILED( hr = g_pD3D->CheckDeviceFormat( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                                            d3ddm.Format, D3DUSAGE_DEPTHSTENCIL,
                                            D3DRTYPE_SURFACE, D3DFMT_D16 ) ) )
{
    if( hr == D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE )
        // POTENTIAL PROBLEM: We need at least a 16-bit z-buffer!
        return hr;
}

//
// Do we support hardware vertex processing? If so, use it.
// If not, downgrade to software.
//

D3DCAPS9 d3dCaps;

if( FAILED( hr = g_pD3D->GetDeviceCaps( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                                   D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, &d3dCaps ) ) )
{
    // TO DO: Respond to failure of GetDeviceCaps
    return hr;
}

DWORD dwBehaviorFlags = 0;

if( d3dCaps.VertexProcessingCaps != 0 )
    dwBehaviorFlags |= D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING;
else
    dwBehaviorFlags |= D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING;

//
// Everything checks out - create a simple, windowed device.
//

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
memset(&d3dpp, 0, sizeof(d3dpp));

d3dpp.BackBufferFormat       = d3ddm.Format;
d3dpp.SwapEffect             = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.Windowed               = TRUE;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
d3dpp.PresentationInterval   = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;

// Attempt to create a HAL device, end app on failure just to keep things
// simple.  In other words we are not trying to create a REF device if the
// HAL fails.
if( FAILED( hr = g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, g_hWnd,
                                  dwBehaviorFlags, &d3dpp, &g_pD3DDevice ) ) )
{
    MessageBox (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
}


// If we get here everything worked!
return S_OK;
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: RenderFrame()
// Desc: Draw the image to the framebuffer.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void RenderFrame( )
{
if (!g_pD3DDevice && !g_pD3DXSprite && !g_pTexture)
    return;


// Clear the frame & depth buffer ready for drawing (Black color)
g_pD3DDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,  0x00000000, 1.0f, 0 );

g_pD3DDevice->BeginScene();
{
    //-------------------------
    // Render the sprite
    //

    D3DXVECTOR3 vecPos = D3DXVECTOR3(0,0,0);

    if (g_pD3DXSprite && g_pTexture)
    {
        g_pD3DXSprite->Begin( D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND );
        g_pD3DXSprite->Draw(g_pTexture, NULL, NULL, &vecPos, 0xffffffff);
        g_pD3DXSprite->End();
    }


}
g_pD3DDevice->EndScene();


// Frame buffer to Front buffer
g_pD3DDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );

}
```

I have tried changing the parameter `g_hWnd` in the `CreateDevice` method to `HWND_DESKTOP`, I figured it would work since you can draw directly to the desktop by drawing to `HWND_DESKTOP` in GDI, unfortunately this simply resulted in the CreateDevice method failing. I looked into the `IDirect3D9` class methods for some way to make a device context with `HWND_DESKTOP` similar to GDI because I suspected that's how I should go about finding a way to draw to the desktop. No luck, I've of course done the obvious google search "how to draw to desktop DirectX"(and various other combinations of the same question) in hopes to find an answer but nothing seems to be turning up, the closest thing I've found is someone drawing a transparent window and drawing the desired contents on top of that window but I thought there's probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: What do you mean by 'deskop'? Desktop background (i.e. wallpaper)? Or drawing on top of all windows? Or anything else?

Comment: on top of all windows and the toolbar, as though I drew to HWND_DESKTOP. Unfortunately I already have made an application that does this with GDI but I'm on XP so it lacks hardware acceleration so I decided to switch to DirectX, which unfortunately is being a real pain to get working correctly.

Comment: If you don't need any fancy 3d stuff, you can try making an application using WPF (not sure though if it is hardware accelerated in Windows XP). Otherwise I don't know how to make it work in XP.

Comment: Have you turned on debug information in the directx control panel?  What reason does it give for the CreateDevice failing?

Comment: I've never heard of the directX control panel, but it gives D3DERR_INVALIDCALL (8876086C)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331240/how-to-enable-more-debugging-info-for-directx-variables-in-vs-2008

Comment: Are you asking about rendering fullscreen, or are you intending to render content literally on top of the desktop? E.g. are you expecting other apps to still show up with your content super-imposed on it?