# Creating instances of classes which only take IntPtr in their constructor

Tags: c#, com, directx, sharpdx

Well I do get most of the DirectX stuff so far. But using SharpDX I've repeatedly stumbled across one and the same issue:

How can you instantiate or get instances of classes which only take an `IntPtr` in their constructor? I don't understand why there are 6 variations of the DXGI `Factory` interface/class (Factory and Factory1 - Factory5). Some can be instantiated via the constructor and some can only be constructed by passing in an `IntPtr`.

So does right now the `PixelFormatInfo` and `PixelFormatInfo2` objects (WIC) which I need to get the bits per pixel of my `BitmapSource`.

I already tried by using `ImagingFactory2` which can be instantiated and then using `QueryInterface(Guid, out IntPtr)` but this only throws an exception (non existing interface) when I pass in the pixel format GUID I get from the `BitmapSource`.

So how does this work? How do I get the pointer I need? And how? In C++ this works by using the `__uuidof` macro in order to get the GUID of the interface - but in C# there's no way I know about. And there's no reference on which interface has which GUID.

Comment: `__uuidof` is not a macro, it is a non-standard operator. Typically it should be avoided and GUID for particular interface supplied explicitly. Reference on which interface has which GUID can be found at interface declaration (which is located at Windows SDK along with header files, for example `dxgi.idl`).

Comment: Ah okay sorry. I'm not very experienced in C++. And you're right. I even found some GUIDs for WIC in the MSDN, nonetheless this wasn't any help. The problem with the pixel format could be solved. There's a static helper method in the struct which I overlooked obviously.

Comment: The code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685483/displaying-large-image-with-sharpdx may point you to what you want to do. Generally, the IntPtr constructors are for use from other SharpDX objects - if you only see IntPtr constructors on a given object, that means you should not be creating it directly.